# Flutter Firebase Crashlytics Failed to connect: Settings request failed

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I want to add Firebase Crashlyctics to my Flutter Android Project.I followed the instructions in the official documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?hl=de&platform=flutter) but when i start my application i get the following error in the debug-console. I get the error that "Settings request failed.". It seems like there are connection problems to *firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/:::443*

```
I/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687): Initializing Firebase Crashlytics 18.4.0 for MY_PROJECT
D/FirebaseSessions( 4687): Registering Sessions SDK subscriber with name: CRASHLYTICS, data collection enabled: true
D/FirebaseSessions( 4687): Data Collection is enabled for at least one Subscriber
E/SessionConfigFetcher( 4687): Error failing to fetch the remote configs: Failed to connect to firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/:::443
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687): Settings request failed.
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687): java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/:::443
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpGetRequest.execute(HttpGetRequest.java:78)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:112)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:200)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:193)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzo.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:67)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 4687):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

My adnroid project has two different flavors, and i configured firebase for both of them. The *google-services.json* and the *firebase_options.dart* seems to be contain the correct app-id and informations.

The crashlytics site still looks like this:

[image]

Has anybody an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are other firebase functionalities working fine? Pls check this out in case you are missing some configuration: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/overview

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes other functionalities like Cloud Messaging work fine. I followed the instructions oin the link, but its not working. I have an multi Flavor app. Maybe thats the problem somehow.